# Protection offered by using assembly StrongName?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, strongname

I get that StrongName don't prevent reflection - that's the job of an obfuscator. But beyond creating rather unique names, what is the cryptographic purpose or protection of using StrongNames?

Assume

1. `MyAssembly` has `internal` classes and methods, which are exposed via 
    `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssemblyTest, PublicKey=RealRSAPublicKey")]` to
2. `MyAssemblyTest`, the testing assembly.

Both those assemblies have StrongNames, perhaps using the same RSA key pairs.

What prevents someone from

1. Stripping the signature on `MyAssembly`
2. Creating a fake/dummy RSA key pair
3. Modifying the assembly attribute to `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("MyAssemblyTest, PublicKey=FakeRSAPublicKey")]`
4. Re-signing `MyAssembly` with their own fake/dummy RSA key pair
5. Consuming the internals inside their own assembly, say `MaliciousAssembly`

I guess I'm not clear what Strongnaming's real duties are ... would appreciate some insight.

Answer (score 0):

The primary purpose of giving an assembly a strong name is preventing malicious users of someone else's code that uses your assembly from substituting your code with their own.

Consider this situation: you make a `TransmitSecret.dll` assembly that you give to your customers so that they could communicate with your server in a secure way. If `TransmitSecret.dll` is not signed, malicious users would be able to write their own module that presents the same interface as yours, wrap your code in their own malicious code, intercept all of "secure" transmissions of your customer, and send a copy to their own server. They would be able to do it without having access to the source code of your customers, simply by replacing your `dll` with theirs.

If `TransmitSecret.dll` is signed, however, and your customers' code is linked against it, the trick with swapping the assemblies is not going to work: when your customers' code would try loading `TransmitSecret.dll`, .NET would notice the change, and stop the program from starting up.